# Использование методов одного класса в другом классе

Tags: ооп, php, методы

Есть 3 файла `MessageController.php`, `MySQLController.php`, `RenderController.php`.

Как мне, допустим, в `MessageController.php` использовать рендер и `mysql`?
Пробовал `__autoload`, но что-то не получилось. Поделитесь советом, как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно было бы использовать `Extends` но унаследовать можно только один класс.

Можно примерно так:

```
//MySQLController.php

class MySQLController
{
    public $controller;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->controller = __CLASS__;
    }
}

$MySQLController = new MySQLController;

//RenderController.php

class RenderController
{
    public $controller;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->controller = __CLASS__;
    }
}

$RenderController = new RenderController;

//MessageController.php

require_once('MySQLController.php'); 
require_once('RenderController.php');

class MessageController
{
    public $controller;

    function __construct()
    {
        global $MySQLController, $RenderController; //область видимости

        $this->controller = $MySQLController->controller;
        //$this->controller = $RenderController->controller;
        //$this->controller = __CLASS__;
    }
}

$MessageController = new MessageController;

echo $MessageController->controller; //MySQLController
```

Comment: global это конечно жутковато. 

Наверное лучше человеку который знакомится с ООП сразу прививать хорошие манеры :)
http://wiki.agiledev.ru/doku.php?id=ooad:dependency_injection

И судя по вопросу тыкать в php.net :)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы использовать методы класса извне, они должны быть, конечно же, открытыми, т.е публичными. Это понятно. Далее, если все эти три файла содержат определенные классы, то там, где используется функционал чужого класса, можно просто инклудить сам класс:

```
require_once("RenderController.php"); // например
```

И далее просто использовать функционал подключенного класса в том файле, к которому он был подключен.

Comment: а внутри класса как инициализировать?

Comment: Прочитайте справку (php.net и прочее) на тему ООП, это снимет много общих вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что внутри Controller надо создать экземпляры MySQLController, RenderController и работать с их методами. На то он и контроллер, чтобы что-то отработать и отдать результат.

Например, внутри контроллера:

```
$this->db = new MySQLController();
$this->view = new RenderController();
$this->someData = $this->db->sampleQuery();
$this->view->render($this->someData);
```

Это паттерн MVC, а то, что Вы желаете просто подергать методы классов - это ерунда. Если просто дергать методы классов, зачем в именах классов смущать читателя намеком на MVC?

Comment: В MVC таки модель это логика, а не просто обертка для доступа к БД. Это на тему вашего примера.

Comment: А чем, к примеру, плох один глобальный экземпляр `$db` вместо создания нового экземпляра каждый раз?

Comment: Глобальный экземпляр может не понадобиться. Например, у нас 100 вьшек, но в каждый запрос к серверу понадобится только одна - иницировать все не имеет смысла. И вроде помню, что все переменные в php-приложении существуют только в период от запроса до ответа сервера, поэтому создать их и оставить висеть в памяти не получится.